# How to access FormArray elements from inside FormGroup?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

```
// Getter function:
  get getCheckboxes_FormGroup()
  {
    return this.objFormGroup.controls.checkboxesBlogs.controls as FormArray;
  }


  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.objFormGroup = this.objFormBuilder.group(
                            {
                              checkboxesBlogs: new FormArray([])
                            }
                          )

    for( var i = 0; i < this.blogs.length; i++)
    {
      // Generate a checkbox for this blog:
      this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.push( this.objFormBuilder.group(
                                              {
                                                blogTitle:       [this.blogs[i].title],
                                                blogId:          [this.blogs[i].id],
                                                checkboxValue:   [false],
                                                body:            [this.blogs[i].body],
                                                creationDate:    [this.blogs[i].creationDate],
                                                modificationDate:[this.blogs[i].modificationDate],
                                                category:        [this.blogs[i].category],
                                                visible:         [true]
                                              }
                                            )
                                        );
    }

}
```

In typescript, I have attempted to access it like this:
 `this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.controls[i].value.visible = false`

This is not giving me errors, but it is not setting the value false also.

In HTML, I have attempted to access it like this:
`<div *ngFor = "let checkboxesBlog of getCheckboxes_FormGroup.controls; " >
                <a *ngIf = "checkboxesBlog.controls.visible.value === true">`

This is not giving me errors, but it is always showing value as true.

**What is the appropriate way of accessing this in typescript and html?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.objFormGroup.controls.checkboxesBlogs.controls` are NOT a FormArray (is an Array of FormGroups

perhafs you want say `this.objFormGroup.controls.checkboxesBlogs`, but it's better use get() to get the control

```
get getCheckboxes_FormGroup()
{
    return this.objFormGroup.get('checkboxesBlogs') as FormArray;
}
```

So

```
this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.at(i) //is the FormGroup.
this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.at(i).get('visible') //is the FormControl
```

if you need change the value you need use "setValue"

```
this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.at(i).get('visible').setValue(true)
```

You can use also

```
this.objFormGroup.get('checkboxesBlogs.'+i+'.visible') //to get the control
this.objFormGroup.get('checkboxesBlogs.'+i+'.visible').setValue(true) //to change the value
```

In .html if only want to get the value

```
getCheckboxes_FormGroup.at(i).get('visible').value
//or
getCheckboxes_FormGroup.value[i].visible
//or
objFormGroup.value.checkboxesBlogs[i].visible'
//or
checkboxesBlog.value.visible  //<--checkboxesBlog is the "variable" you loop
checkboxesBlog.get('visible').value  //<--checkboxesBlog is the "variable" you loop
```

See that you use "value" to get the value, if you get the value of the form you need "go throught" this value, and you can get the value of the array or the control

See the docs: [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) and [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray)